# Getting XYZ coordinates of Cylindrical family instances(copy)

Tags: c#, revit-api

**this is the copy of the post in Revit API forums

Hi,

I have multiple instances of cylinder based family in my project. The instances were created using the following code line:

FamilyInstance element = document.Create.NewFamilyInstance(location, symbol, StructuralType.NonStructural);

The location of the family instance is composed of X and Y coordinates while the Z coordinate remains 0.0

e.g (-6.2, 65.6, 0.0).

The length of the cylindrical family instances is controlled by a Depth parameter, Such that where one instance ends (in Z direction ) another instance starts.

Now after the creation of family instances i want to Retrieve the XYZ coordinates of the family insertion point, which i do with the following code:

```html
// remove duplicate values from geo_famtyp_names list
                List<string> distinct_geo_famtyp_names = geo_famtyp_names.Distinct().ToList();

                //ITERATE OVER EACH TYPE NAME PRESENT IN THE LIST AND RETRIEVE A COLECTION OF ELEMENTS AND THEN PERFORM OTHER FUNCTIONS
                foreach (string typename in distinct_geo_famtyp_names) 
                {
                    List<XYZ> positions = new List<XYZ>();
                    var paramId = new ElementId(BuiltInParameter.SYMBOL_FAMILY_AND_TYPE_NAMES_PARAM);
                    var fam_type = String.Format("{0}: {1}", "BAUER_Fam_GeologyLayer", typename);
                    var rule = ParameterFilterRuleFactory.CreateEqualsRule(paramId, fam_type, true);
                    var filter = new ElementParameterFilter(rule);
                    var elem_collec = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).OfClass(typeof(FamilyInstance)).WherePasses(filter).ToList();
                    
                    // GET A LIST OF POSITIONS FOR EACH ELEMENT OF A SPECIFIC FAM TYPE
                    foreach (FamilyInstance el in elem_collec) 
                    {
                       
                        XYZ elem_pos = ((LocationPoint)el.Location).Point;
                        if (!(positions.Contains(elem_pos)))
                        {
                            positions.Add(elem_pos);
                        }

                    }
```

The problem is that with this code, I am getting only the X and Y coordinate values for each Family instance while the Z coordinate remains 0.0

After getting the XYZ coordinates i have to create a topography surface which joins family instances of same Family types.

Any guideance on how to retrieve the value of z coordinate as well, would be greatly  helpful .

Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [RPTHOMAS108](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/1035859) in the Revit API discussion forum thread on [Getting XYZ coordinates of Cylindrical family instances](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/revit-api-forum/getting-xyz-coordinates-of-cylindrical-family-instances/td-p/11250721): The family is an adaptive component; strange, it has lost its location point reference for Z. Probably due to how it was authored, i.e., point not constrained correctly in family. If you are stuck with a problem to solve then you can refer to the `BoundingBox` Z values in short term.

Comment: Thanks for Sharing Jeremy, It seems to be a suitable solution, i will go on with this.